# JQuery ajax cleanup code before closing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

Before closing/navigating away from my web page I need to call a 'cleanup code' function using jQuery AJAX. If, and only if, the clean up code fails, I want to display an `alert` and prevent closing/navigation. Otherwise the page should close successfully without any confirmation dialog.

I called my cleanup AJAX in an `onbeforeunload` event handler, and omitted the `return` statement from the handler to prevent the confirmation dialog. The cleanup works, but now I can't `alert` to the user in case of clean up failure!

Any suggestions on how to `alert` to the user on failure and prevent closing, please?

```
window.onbeforeunload =  function(e) { 
  MyCleanUpCode(); 
};
```

Comment: That sequence is not possible within `beforeunload`. You must determine synchronously whether to show the prompt or not

Comment: Note: `return undefined` has the same effect as not using return at all.

Comment: Suggest you reconsider approach and do cleanup on periodic interval and use some sort of `dirty` flag when user changes something in between cleanups and use that flag to show unload prompt. Also you can not use an `alert()` inside that event handler

Comment: @charlietfl: i edited the code. do you need more details?


Besides, my clean up must be before closing because it unlocks some records on database since user finished working on them

Comment: Not really. Your choices are show the prompt or not and that is about all you can control. If the ajax is critical you need to take care of it before user tries to leave

Comment: @charlietfl: but when cleanup fails, i need to tell user and entirely prevent closing, not confirm closing !

Comment: I know that's what you would like but it is just not that simple. What if users browser crashes or they lose power? That event and ajax would never even occur.

Comment: do you think placing clean up code on server's Session_End event would be better ?

Comment: Safest approach is do server updates or localStorage updates for every change user makes then there is no cleanup needed